# codes within php tags doesn't get executed

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, shell-exec

I upgraded my system from Ubuntu 15.10 to Ubuntu 16.04 and now the code doesn't execute within php tags even though I install Apache2 and Php again.
I only see the form as shown here and don't see the output of `ls -ltr`
[image]

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>


<?php

$output = shell_exec('ls -ltr');
var_dump($output);
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>


</body>
</html>

 php -v
PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Insert `<?php echo "aaaaaaaaa"; ?>` as the first line of your code. Is the text being displayed?

Comment: done any basic debugging, like a `view source` of the page? If you see your PHP code in the browser, then PHP isn't running or is misconfigured.

Comment: create a new PHP file and put `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it. What happens when you view it? Guessing you get a blank page. If so.. 
`sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt php-mysql`   yo installed the CLI, but that's not the PHP interpreter that Apache uses

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez no it is not displayed!

Comment: @MonaJalal Reinstall mod_php.

Comment: @DuaneLortie when I create a new .php file and put `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` I can see the famous light putple php info page. I already had that installed and still I don't see anything that I use within php tags

Comment: @ceejayoz how? What is the complete command?

Comment: The command to re-install libapache2- mod-php  etc is in my answer below.
which you say is already installed.. well, it installed incorrectly somehow. Suggest re-installing.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you installed PHP-CLI, but that's not the PHP interpreter that Apache uses, OR Apache isn't configured to use the correct interpreter. This command should fix either scenario.

```
 `sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt php-mysql`
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I still can't see anything within the php tags. Also I already had this installed

Comment: Be sure to restart Apache after any changes...

`sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Comment: I did restart it before but didn't change!

Comment: Also I reinstalled it using `sudo apt-get install --reinstall php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt php-mysql` and then restarted the apache `sudo systemctl restart apache2` but still don't get to see anything executed between the php tags

Answer (score 0):

Switched to Google Chrome now it is working! Prior to upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 it was working in Firefox too.

Comment: This defies logic. What browser you use *SHOULD* have no effect at all on whether your server parses PHP :/